# How to search by any word in any field with ElasticSearch rest high-level client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I tried to search any contract witch contains some key word, but my code is incorrect:

```
 public Collection<Map<String, Object>> findContractsByWord(String index, String type, String word) throws CommonUserException {
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index);
    searchRequest.types(type);
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("", word));
    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse searchResponse;
    try (RestHighLevelClient client = getClient()) {
        searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CommonUserException("Exception in elasticsearch", "Exception in elasticsearch");
    }
    SearchHit[] hits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
    Collection<Map<String, Object>> contracts = new LinkedList<>();
    for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
        contracts.add(hit.getSourceAsMap());
    }
    return contracts;
}
```

Maybe someone knows how to do this with rest high-level client? (elastic 6.2.4)

Comment: what kind of error you have? could you post it?

Comment: It just doesn't find any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem using `MultSearchRequest` and `wildcardQuery()`:

```
MultiSearchRequest request = new MultiSearchRequest();

    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, ID_FIELD, word));
    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, PROVIDER_ID_FIELD, word));
    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, LEGAL_NUMBER_FIELD, word));
    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, OWNER_FIELD, word));
    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, STATUS_FIELD, word));
    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, START_DATE_FIELD, word));
    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, END_DATE_FIELD, word));
    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, PRODUCT_CODE_FIELD, word));
    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, SUBPRODUCT_CODE_FIELD, word));
    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, CUSTOM_STATUS_FIELD, word));
    request.add(formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(index, type, SUB_STATUS_FIELD, word));

    MultiSearchResponse searchResponse;
    try (RestHighLevelClient client = getClient()) {
        searchResponse = client.multiSearch(request);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CommonUserException(ELASTIC_EXCEPTION, ELASTIC_EXCEPTION);
    }
    Collection<Map<String, Object>> contracts = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < searchResponse.getResponses().length; i++) {
        SearchHit[] hits = searchResponse.getResponses()[i].getResponse().getHits().getHits();
        for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
            contracts.add(hit.getSourceAsMap());
        }
    }
    return contracts;
}

private SearchRequest formSearchRequestForMultiSearch(String index, String type, String field, String word) {
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index);
    searchRequest.types(type);
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery(field, word));
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    return searchRequest;
}
```

Comment: I am getting issue in client.multiSearch(request)  as The method multiSearch(MultiSearchRequest) is undefined for the type RestHighLevelClient